# Apache LDAP authorization

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-auth-ldap

I am attempting to use mod_auth_cas for AuthN and LDAP for AuthZ.  mod_cas_auth is actually irrelevant, because I have the same issue with BasicAuth for AuthN.
Everything works fine if I specify `<location "/">`, but as soon as I specify a sublocation `<Location "/secure">` the authorisation fails and I get a 403.

e.g. this works and permits access to people in the specified LDAP group:

```
<Location "/">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile var/ht.passwd
  AuthName Secure
  AuthLDAPUrl         "ldaps://<snip>?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
  AuthLDAPBindDN      "CN=<snip>
  AuthLDAPBindPassword <snip>
  Require ldap-group CN=<snip>
</Location>
```

But this doesn't - it just returns 403 to everyone

```
<Location "/secure">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile var/ht.passwd
  AuthName Secure
  AuthLDAPUrl         "ldaps://<snip>?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
  AuthLDAPBindDN      "CN=<snip>
  AuthLDAPBindPassword <snip>
  Require ldap-group CN=<snip>
</Location>
```

In the logs for the 2nd situation I have:

`auth_ldap authorise: User DN not found, ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed`

This is on Apache 2.2.  I'm thinking this must be a bug, but wondered if there was anything I could do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

But why you still use "AuthUserFile"? this works for me:

> ```
>             AuthType Basic
>             AuthName "Some name"
>             Require ldap-group <snip>
>             SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth
>             AuthBasicProvider ldap
>             AuthLDAPBindDN uid=<snip>
>             AuthLDAPBindPassword <snip>
>             AuthLDAPURL ldaps://<server>/<basedn>?uid?sub
>             AuthLDAPRemoteUserAttribute uid
>             AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
>             Options MultiViews
> ```

Error " User DN not found" tells you about auth problem. So, check your authbinddn and authbindpassword, for example with ldapsearch:
 ldapsearch -H ldap://server -x -D cn=